# Current line number in vim not highlighted with relative line number

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, highlight, line-numbers

So I have relative line numbers turned on with the gruvbox theme and I'm trying to get highlighting of the current line number that I'm on. This works by default when just enabling relative line numbers in the .vimrc of an ssh session but not otherwise. I've tried using `:set cursorline` but that marks the whole line not just the line number. This is on a mac btw

[How it looks in an ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9uyt.png) vs [how it looks not in an ssh session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvpRK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can enable cursorline

```
:set cursorline
```

Comment: This is what I ended up settling with. I guess it looks better that way